# The metric space and algebraic structure

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The metric space is not an algebraic structure so we don't have laws "+" But in the definition of metric (distance) we use "+" in triangular inegalite. How come?
And what is that "+"

Comment: The image of the metric lies in $\mathbb{R}_+$, which is given the usual $+$ operation. / Une distance est à valeurs dans $\mathbb{R}_+$ muni de l'addition usuelle.

Comment: A distance function on a metric space $S$ can be modelized as a function $d:S \times S \to \mathbb{R}$ ; therefore the "+" operation is made in the image set of the distance function, $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

A metric space $(X,d)$ is a set $X$ where we talk about distance between any two points.This "distance" is made precise by defining a distance function $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ on the set $X$.This means that distance between two points $x$ and $y$ is the real number $d(x,y)$. Thia distance always satisfies:

(i) it is always non-negative,

(ii) distance is zero if and only if they are same point,

(iii) distance should be symmetric i.e. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$, for all $x,y \in X$

(iv) the triangle inequality, which says that if we take a triangle,then sum of its two sides should always be greater than or equal to other side i.e. $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$.The '+' you talking about would be sum of two real numbers $d(x,y)$ and $d(y,z)$.

Comment: "A metric space is a space where we talk about distance between any two points". Isn't that a bit vague? I would have said $(E,d)$, where $E$ is a set and $d:E\times E\to \mathbb R$ such that...